# Odd behaviour onCanExecute RelayCommand MVVMLight 5+

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm migrating a tool from MVVM Light 4.0.3 to 5.4.1 and I have found a very odd issue with the newest **RelayCommand** implementation.

This is the old implementation in the **V4.0.3**:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

This is the newest implementation in the **V5.4.1**:

[image: img4]

[image: img3]

Before I was able to use variables to define the **canExecute** behaviour (enabled a button) with the following code:

```
public ICommand GetNewItemsFromDB { get; private set; }

private bool _IsActive;
public bool IsActive
{
    get
    {
        return _IsActive;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_IsActive != value)
        {
            _IsActive = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsActive);
        }
    }
}

GetNewItemsFromDB = new RelayCommand(GetDataFromDB, () => { return IsActive == false; });

private void GetDataFromDB()
{
    IsActive = true;
}
```

The previous code was able to enable the button without any issue in the MVVM Light 4.0.3; however, in the newest implementation is always disabled, I added changed a bit since there is a new definition of **keepTargetAlive**:

```
GetNewItemsFromDB = new RelayCommand(GetDataFromDB, () => { return IsActive == false; }, true);
```

Also, I tried the **false** option and nothing changed. The only way that I found to re-enabled it, it was to set a predefined value like this one:

```
GetNewItemsFromDB = new RelayCommand(GetDataFromDB, () => true, true);
```

This implementation is going to be useless in my case since the RelayCommand (in namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command) depends on the variable **IsActive**, which determines if it's enabled or not. Does anyone what I should change in the **V5** to make it work? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly.

> If you are using this class in WPF4.5 or above, you need to use the
>   `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf` namespace (instead of
>   `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command`). This will enable (or restore) the
>   CommandManager class which handles automatic enabling/disabling of
>   controls based on the CanExecute delegate.

And in the release notes:

> **Important note about issue 7659**: In order to fix the issue where the
>   controls are not disabled anymore depending on the state of the
>   RelayCommand.CanExecute delegate, you need to make a small change into
>   your code. To opt-in into the fixed behavior, please change the
>   namespace you are using from `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command` to
>   `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf`.

I remember correctly, somewhere in ancient history I had to do this myself for a project.